# Specific Sub categories within tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I am new to this website although I have encountered it many times for programming (SO) support. Is it possible to get sub categories within a `tag`? Please direct me if that ability is already there.

e.g. I look at C# and I want to see C# related theoritical questions, practical or random questions.

- C# to SQL Server connections
- C# serialization/deserialization
- Basics of C#
- C# OOP concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Multiple tags page will bring only questions tagged with all the given tags. For example, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) + [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) will give [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+sql-server?sort=active&pagesize=50).
2. Search within a specific tag, e.g. search for "OOP concepts" in questins tagged with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) will give you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20OOP%20concepts).

Other than this there isn't really "sub categories" for tags unless of course there is separate tag e.g. [c#-4.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) which is for questions targetted for the specific version 4.0 of C#.

Comment: Thank you for the two options. Yes I noticed system has been doing that automatically. If I am on `C#` and click on another tag. I got questions under C# then by secondary tag. I also noticed that tags appear in the right hand side of the SO page is actually named as `related tags` :)

Comment: Yes indeed, you noticed right. :-)